# Exclude some URLs in Django for Sentry Performance tracing

Tags: django, sentry

I have a Django application with a health check endpoint that's using [django-health-check](https://github.com/revsys/django-health-check).

In the `url_patterns` I have added the following line:

```
  url(r'^ht/', include('health_check.urls')),
```

The issue is that the health check is filling all the Sentry transaction limits.

How can I exclude the health check endpoint in Sentry?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way to handle this kind of cases is to use a [sampling function](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/django/configuration/sampling/#setting-a-sampling-function) to control the sample rate according to the URL or other parameters.

```py
def traces_sampler(ctx):
    if 'wsgi_environ' in ctx:
        url = ctx['wsgi_environ'].get('PATH_INFO', '')
        if url.startswith('/ht/'):
            return 0  # Don't trace any
    return 1  # Trace all

sentry_sdk.init(
    # ...
    traces_sampler=traces_sampler,
)
```

Here is a more complete example.

```py
def traces_sampler(ctx):
    if ctx['parent_sampled'] is not None:
        # If this transaction has a parent, we usually want to sample it
        # if and only if its parent was sampled.
        return ctx['parent_sampled']
    op = ctx['transaction_context']['op']
    if 'wsgi_environ' in ctx:
        # Get the URL for WSGI requests
        url = ctx['wsgi_environ'].get('PATH_INFO', '')
    elif 'asgi_scope' in ctx:
        # Get the URL for ASGI requests
        url = ctx['asgi_scope'].get('path', '')
    else:
        # Other kinds of transactions don't have a URL
        url = ''
    if op == 'http.server':
        # Conditions only relevant to operation "http.server"
        if url.startswith('/ht/'):
            return 0  # Don't trace any of these transactions
    return 0.1  # Trace 10% of other transactions

sentry_sdk.init(
    # ...
    traces_sampler=traces_sampler,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily filter the events sent to the sentry by using the  `before_breadcrumb` function in sentry. [This function](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/enriching-events/breadcrumbs/#customize-breadcrumbs) allows you to apply any filter you want on the sentry logs before sending them to the sentry. if you return `None` in the `before_breadcrumb` function, it will not send anything to the sentry.

Your code would be like this:

```
import sentry_sdk

def before_breadcrumb(crumb, hint):
    if 'httplib_request' in hint:
        # Check the request URL and return None if it is health check
    return crumb

sentry_sdk.init(
    # ...

    before_breadcrumb=filter_events,
)
```